# Check parameters or handle exception

Tags: java, performance, exception

Our team have a method that gets 3 parameters and calls to a substring method

```
    String result = "";
    String paramString = request.getParameter("paramString");
    String paramStart = request.getParameter("paramStart");
    String paramEnd = request.getParameter("paramEnd");
    
    if (params are not empty and start and end are numbers) {
        try {
            result = paramString.substring(Integer.valueOf(paramStart), Integer.valueOf(paramEnd))
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            //log error 
        }
    }
    return result;
```

But some people in the teams says that we should avoid the try catch block and validate that start >= 0, start <= end, and end <= StringLength before calling to the substring method. They say we should avoid the throw of the exception in the substring method because thowing and catching the exception is "less efficient" than avoiding it.
Personally I see these totally unnecessary even if it's slightly better. Firstly, because you are doing the same validation as substring do, and secondly because you are making the code less legible.

So the question is... should we check parameters before calling to the method or should we relay in the handling exception? Does the performance "justify" the extra validation of the parameters before calling the method?

In a general case... should we try to avoid all exceptions or can we relay in try catch blocks (witout catching general `Exception`)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have performance issues? In general performance optimisation without having performance issues is bad practice. Better focus on what makes the code more readable.

Comment: No performance issues at all, but some people seems to be a little obsessed with performance

Comment: Why not throwing *Runtime* exceptions ? This way, you do not force the consumers to introduce a try catch, and you have a clear feedback

Comment: Definitely no point prematurely optimising, especially with something like this. Also you said that adding the checks makes it less legible, but I completely disagree, the checks would make it much clearer.

Comment: @Henry Trust me, the alternative have several levels of nested ifs and calls to the substring method in at least 3 execution flows. This isn't clear at all, but maybe this isn't related to validate parameters.